# Chaincode calling is a transaction?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I have a comprehensive question; when a chaincode calls another chaincode is this considered a transaction?

Answer (score 2):

@ghaskins:
I believe it all executes under the originating transaction
i.e. the second chaincode would see the tcert context of the caller that hit the first chaincode
though I would also like to see the identity of the calling chaincode represented somehow, i dont think this is in place today

@muralisr: 
there’s only one transaction… the one initiated by the user